# How to get birthdate C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I need some help.

I'm writing an webapplication in asp.net C#, I want to get the next birthday. I have.

1 field name birthdate, type DateTime. Ex: `1991-01-02 00:0000:0000 (yyyy-MM-dd)`. I want to show people have next birthday in repeater.

```
select * from tblBirthday where birthdate between 2015-01-01 and datenow
```

But now all I get in code behind with `datetime.now` is `string` type, birthdate is `datetime` type.
How I can get datetime.now with `datetime` type.

Comment: With `datenow` you mean `DateTime.Now`? If so, it is not a string, it's a DateTime. We need to see your code behind code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in c#, you are passing DateTime.Now and not DateTime.Now.ToString()
or you can do your formatting of datetime "dd-MM-yy" and then cast it to proper datetime object like below...

```
 DateTime datetimenow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly your `datenow` is? Try to use the stored procedure, and make the date a parameter with `datetime` sql type, so it will work for a `BETWEEN` constructure, or use the built-in `GETDATE()` function on sql server side, like this:

```
select * from tblBirthday where birthdate between 2015-01-01 and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

use Sql [CAST AND CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

> Syntax for CAST: CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
>
> Syntax for CONVERT: CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [
> , style ] )

like.

```
select * from tblBirthday where Cast(birthdate as date) between 
cast('01/01/2015' as date) and cast(getdate() as date)
--where getdate() is the sql function to get current datetime.
```